# store inputs into list of string in python

Tags: python

Is there any other optimized and simple way to store inputs into a list of string.

Input

```
bcdef
abcdefg
bcde
bcdef
```

output

```
['bcdef', 'abcdefg', 'bcde', 'bcdef']
```

below is the code I tried to code

```
l = []
for i in range(4):
    l.append(input())
print(l)
```

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me. What's the problem?

Comment: yeah I know that's fine I am figuring is there any other best way to do tath

Comment: If you want to iterate over stdin, maybe you want [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html)?

Answer (score 4):

You could also write this as a list comprehension, like this:

```
l = [input() for i in range(4)]
print(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```py
import sys
l = sys.stdin.read().split()
```

You will need to run `Ctrl+D` once you have entered you input.

Comment: actually I am solving the problem in hackerank i don't is this works

Comment: @savershkumar, just try it and let me know

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
l = [input(), input(), input(), input()]
```

Comment: this will work as long as he has to enter 4 strings.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. This provided answer may be correct, but **it could benefit from an explanation**. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).